# How to rollback transaction after class (using TestNg and Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, testng

Let's say we have the next test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyDaoContext.class})
public class MyDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

@Autowired
private MyDao dao;

@Test
public void insertDataTest() {
    // insert data here and test something
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "insertDataTest")
public void modifyPreviouslyInsertedDataTest() {
    // get previously inserted data and test something
}
}
```

Second test will fall because when we have finished first test the inserted data are gone.
Is there a way to rollback a transaction after all tests have finished their work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each test runs in its own transaction and rollbacks at the end. You can tune that by adding `@Rollback(false)` to your first test.

The problem now is that the transaction of `insertDataTest` has completed so you should remove what it has created manually. To do that, the class you extends from has several utility methods such as `deleteFromTables` or `deleteFromTableWhere`.

This should go ideally in an `@AfterClass` or something.

But that's not what I would do. I would factor out the data that are inserted by `insertDataTest` in a shared utility. That way, you could call it again in your second test and remove the `dependsOnMethods`. Having such dependency is not recommended as you can't run that test in isolation.

Comment: Is there a way to use spring to do this work for me? (deleteFromTables or deleteFromTableWhere)

Comment: Well you're already using Spring when you invoke those methods. What are you after exaclty?

Comment: Hi, "factor out the data inserted by insertDataTest in a shared utility". Please explain more on this

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (which would work in JUnit, I'm not sure about TestBG)

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyDaoContext.class})
public class MyDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

   @Autowired
   private MyDao dao;

   @Test
   @Rollback(false)
   public void insertDataTest() {
       // insert data here and test something
   }

   @Test(dependsOnMethods = "insertDataTest")
   public void modifyPreviouslyInsertedDataTest() {
       // get previously inserted data and test something
   }
}
```

In that case of course you would have to delete the data from the first method manually

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if I add @Rollback(false) data will remain in DB after all test are finished. I need data in DB only during the test and I need to roll back all insertions afrer tests are finished.